# CSS replace media query that has 1px min-width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

In my main css (which I don't have access to) I have a media query

```
@media (min-width: 1px) {
  .some-class {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

That media query seems to overwrite all other media queries. :(

This results in `.some-class` always displaying `none` (The example is simplified. In my original code there are more classes and properties in the media query.)

I have to replace that media query with `min-width: 768px`. I tried:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .some-class {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

..and it doesn't override.

I don't have access to the main css and can't change the order of the stylesheets. How can I remove/replace the `min-width:0` media query so that it uses properties from a `min-width:768` media query?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .some-class {
  display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: You dont have acces to the main css and you cant change the order of the stylesheets? So you also dont have acces to the main html/php?